# when i'm trying to create react file it is showing me error

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

when I'M trying to create react file by `npx create-react-app my-app` it is showing me the error  `A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app. Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported. You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.` even I tried to unstall it as mention in code by `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` but nothing is working. Please help anyone if have any idea what's going on?[image: see the screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried `npm update`?

Comment: yes i tried but the error was not there , have mention the solution i found on Internet

Answer (score 1):

after using all the solution on the Internet i came across a solution which works for me so I like to give solution so that anyone who is looking for similar doubt can get help.

Solution was :

`npx clear-npx-cache`

Then do: `npx create-react-app your-app`